# Why would a Python program take up more than one CPU?

Tags: python, linux, kernel, cpu

[image]

I run python program under linux. But I found a python occasionally takes up more than one CPU.
Notice that it means sometimes it takes up 100% CPU, sometimes it takes up 1500%CPU or more.
Doesn't a python program take up only 100% CPU at most?

Does it have something to do with the following code?

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=9999999)
def get_file(code_file_path):
    code_df = pd.read_csv(code_file_path, index_col=['time', 'code'], parse_dates=['time'])
    return code_df
```

Comment: Do you have an 8-core with HT CPU or 16 core CPU?

Comment: 1. Python code can use more than 1 CPU, but the GIL adds some limitations there. 2. You are using Pandas, which is mostly C code.

Comment: @Martheen I have two CPUs, each 20 cores, overall 40cores.

Comment: @KlausD. But as you can see the picture above, PID(897938) always use 100% CPU at most, and it uses pandas too. Using pandas in which way may lead to a program taking up more than one CPU ?

Comment: python on more than one CPU? maybe if the instructions inside your code can be dissected in many peices but I'm not sure it is possible with GIL. But @Golden Fish give the good andswer...the explanation can come from the fact that there are some C extensions used.